# Query dataframe using spark-sql from remote client

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a client application from where I need to remotely execute queries on spark using spark-sql. I am able to do it from spark-shell but how can I remotely execute them from my scala based client application.
I have tried the following code :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.shuffle.blockTransferService", "nio").setMaster("spark://master:port").setAppName("Query Fire").set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "true")
        .set("spark.local.dir", "/tmp/spark-temp")
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "4G").set("spark.executor.memory", "4G")

  val spark = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
```

I tried giving the default port 7077 but it is not open. I have a cloudera based spark installation which it seems is not running spark standalone.

The error I get running the code when I try to give yarn resourcemanager port 8042 is the following:

> 16/09/16 20:14:36 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in
>   connection from /192.168.0.171:8042 java.io.IOException: Connection
>   reset by peer     at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)

Is there any way to get around this to remotely call spark-sql via jdbc client like we can do for Hive queries??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[apache-spark]%20thrift%20server

Comment: I read Hive Thift Server is not suitable to for High Concurrent Application access. I am unable to access the temp table I created in spark-shell from beeline. Any solutions?

Comment: Spark isn't suitable for this type of applications from the beginning. And if table is not accessible you probably use different context for to register table and start thrift.